# Intersection of two linked lists

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Given two sorted linked lists, L1 and L2, a solution to compute their
intersection **L1 intersection L2**.

Comment: The purpose of SO is to inculcate knowledge and understanding, not to give you complete solutions to vague problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
L1_node = L1.head;
L2_node = L2.head;
Result = new SList;
while L1_node != NULL and L2_node != NULL:
  if L1_node.value == L2_node.value:
     Result.append(L1_node.value)
     L1_node = L1_node.next
     L2_node = L2_node.next
  elif L1_node.value < L2_node.value:
     L1_node = L1_node.next
  else
     L2_node = L2_node.next
```

(Translate to C yourself.)

Comment: There's an error in that. In the == case, you're not skipping anything - you'll get an infinite series of L1_node.value.

Comment: Perhaps it was left as an exercise in debugging for the OP? If I was to hire someone, and posed this exact interview question, and got this exact solution back, I would question his motives for starting a job as a programmer if he simply parroted an answer he found online.

Comment: @Lasse - maybe, and not a bad idea. My error below was deliberate, honest <hides face in shame at blatant lie>.

Comment: When it comes to homework and interview questions here on Stack Overflow, my gut reaction is to try to guide the person in the right direction, instead of just dumping the answer on him. When you're hiring programmers, you want people that can think, learn and apply, not people who can use Copy/Paste. Well, know-how of Copy/Paste is a bonus.

Comment: @Lasse - agreed, when I think about it. Anyway, the skipping fix here isn't just a matter of copying one of the other cases - it still has a possible gotcha.

Comment: As for the underlying algorithm, one very much like it should be in any half-decent algorithms textbook anyway. Tape may be dead, but there's still arrays, bulk operations on tree data structures etc.

Comment: @Steve: Oops. Fixed. Thanks for spotting (and that's why you should use a standard library function instead of make one up yourself).

Comment: @KennyTM - you're making a *unique* assumption - depending on something that Lasse leaves unstated, I think you may find it's still broken ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Now I don't know what's wrong. Even if the list has duplicated items (e.g. `[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]` vs `[0, 2, 2, 4]`) the algorithm should still give the correct answer (`[2, 2, 4]`).

Comment: @KennyTM - that's the point. You're assuming that non-unique inputs should lead to non-unique outputs. An intersection is a set operation, which kind of implies that may not be true - a set has unique values, so [2, 2, 4] isn't a set. My own solution (to the union) assumes that the output should be a set, but tolerates non-unique inputs - still producing a uniqued set as output. I made an assumption about an unstated requirement and guessed differently to you - it was seeing you code with a different assumption that made me realise the required output isn't unambiguously defined.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are singly linked lists if the two linked lists intersect they would form a Y shape with one arm longer or equal to the other. Let l1 be the length of L1 list and l2 be the length of L2 list.

Suppose that l1 > l2.
Start matching the pointers of List L1 from point (l1-l2) and list L2 from its beginning where ever they point to the same node that node will be the matching point.

If l2 is greater than l1 then do the other way.

Answer (score 0):

How about the solution below, it is O(n+m) and takes a dummy node which is pointing to the Head node. The Head node is a class level variable here, so even if L1 is pointing to the current, Head always has the full list.

I have compiled and tested, runs fine for simple inputs like L1: 1->5>6>7>8>10 and L2:2>4>6>8 , output is 6>8

Any ideas about how to go with unsorted lists? I couldnt think of a O(n) solution

`public Node ReturnIntersection(Node Head, Node L2)
{
if ((Head == null) || (L2 == null))
              return null;`

```
     Node temp = null;
      Node L1 = Head;


      while (L1.next != null && L2.next != null)
      {
          if (L1.data == L2.data)
          {
              L1 = L1.next;
              L2 = L2.next;
          }

          else if (L1.data < L2.data)
          {
              temp = L1.next;
              L1.data = temp.data;
              L1.next = temp.next;

          }

          else if (L1.data > L2.data)
          {
              L2 = L2.next;

          }

      }

      if (L1 != null)
      {
          while (L1.next != null)
          {
              L1.next = null;

          }
      }
      return Head;


  }
```